# Is there a better alternative for a right outer join in Spark DataFrame? And how to conditionally transform rows?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My apologies in advance for a long question. I'll try my best to explain with a minimal example. I have the following two Data Frames **df1** and **df2**

**df1:**

```
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|   PID| CATEGORY| REGION| VOLUME| RESULT|
+------+-------- +-------+-------+-------+
|123456|    CAT-1|  NORTH|    200|  1.345|
|123456|    CAT-1|  SOUTH|    125|  2.890|
|123456|    CAT-2|  NORTH|     75|  6.755|
|123456|    CAT-2|  SOUTH|    100|  0.432|
|123456|    CAT-3|  NORTH|     50|  5.111|
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**df2**

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| CATEGORY| REGION| avgCol|
+-------- +-------+-------+
|    CAT-1|  NORTH|  0.575|
|    CAT-1|  SOUTH| 15.879|
|    CAT-2|  NORTH|  5.255|
+---------+-------+-------+
```

I want to join these two DFs to get a 3rd DF that looks like
**df3**

```
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   PID| CATEGORY| REGION| avgCol| VOLUME| RESULT|
+------+-------- +-------+-------+-------+-------+
|123456|    CAT-1|  NORTH|  0.575|    200|  1.345|
|123456|    CAT-1|  SOUTH| 15.879|    125|  2.890|
|123456|    CAT-2|  NORTH|  5.255|     75|  6.755|
|123456|    CAT-2|  SOUTH|   null|    100|  0.432|
|123456|    CAT-3|  NORTH|   null|     50|  5.111|
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I used right outer join for this. The code looks like

```
DataFrame df3 = df1.join(df2, joinCols, "right_outer");
```

where **joinCols** is the collection of columns I want to join on.

Then, I want to transform **df3** into a Data Frame in which the value of **RESULT** is newly computed only for rows where **avgCol** is null. The code that achieves this looks like

```
df3.withColumn("NEW_RESULT", when(col("avgCol").isNotNull(), getResult(avgCol).otherwise(col("RESULT"))
    .drop("RESULT").withColumnRenamed("NEW_RESULT", "RESULT)
```

So **df4** looks like

```
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   PID| CATEGORY| REGION| avgCol| VOLUME| RESULT|
+------+-------- +-------+-------+-------+-------+
|123456|    CAT-1|  NORTH|  0.575|    200|  8.543|
|123456|    CAT-1|  SOUTH| 15.879|    125|  4.321|
|123456|    CAT-2|  NORTH|  5.255|     75|  7.012|
|123456|    CAT-2|  SOUTH|   null|    100|  0.432|
|123456|    CAT-3|  NORTH|   null|     50|  5.111|
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**NOTE:** I'm dropping and renaming the column as RESULT because I want to use this table for my next iteration.

Now, this produces expected results, but is not performant. Especially, when I enclose this is a loop and the number join columns keeps increasing, it takes a long time for the join and the subsequent operation. Every iteration, it becomes worse.

My question is - Is there a more efficient way to do both/one of these operations in Spark, preferably using Data Frames?

I read a few posts suggesting to analyze the physical plan of the join operation to find ways to optimize, but I couldn't gather much from that. I'm unable to include it here because it is huge. It would be really helpful if anyone can point me to specific things to look at in the physical plan.

I'm running this on a single Spark node (standalone) - version 1.6.1. My code is written in Java. The machine on which I'm running this has abundant processing power and memory. So, I'm pretty sure that's not an issue. Any help with this is much appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm reading the base data off a CSV file using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). **df1** and **df2** are the result of some simple group by + aggregations which I believe is not the bottleneck.

Comment: I have a similar issue. So far, I haven't been able to find an optimal way of doing it